# delete hibernate entity without (attempting to) delete association table (view) entry

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, many-to-many

Entity A and B have a many to many relationship using link table AtoB.

If Entity A is deleted, the related links are deleted by hibernate. So far so good.

My problem is that my link table is a view hiding a much more complicated relationship and works perfectly in this situation except when hiberate tries to delete the link rows from the view, causing the database to complain.

```
@Entity A...   

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "AtoB", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
 public Set<A> getASet() {
     return ASet;
 }
```

Is there a way to get hibernate to not delete the link rows? I haven't found any cascade options or the ability to use `updateable=false` etc on an association.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this issue and the following worked for me:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "V_LoanSecuredUser",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "loanAdditionalInfo_id", updatable = false),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userAuthentication_Id", updatable = false))
@Persister(impl = ReadOnlyCollectionPersister.class)
@Immutable
public class ReadOnlyCollectionPersister extends BasicCollectionPersister {
    public ReadOnlyCollectionPersister(Collection collection,
            CacheConcurrencyStrategy cache, Configuration cfg,
            SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws MappingException,
            CacheException {
        super(collection, cache, cfg, factory);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRowDeleteEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRowInsertEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@ManyToMany(
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
...
```

See [JPA Annotations](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/jpa/resources/toplink-jpa-annotations.html#CHDHJFCI) for cascade types.

Comment: Cascade settings affects behaviour onto the targeted entity, not the associationTable directly.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be using the "link table" design incorrectly, if you want to model this as a ManyToMany relationship. You might want to look at breaking the extra items stored in this table into a separate table or storage.