# Spring data - Deletion is suppressed with relation to view

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I have two entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
public class MyTable {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 18)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_TABLE_seq", sequenceName = "MY_TABLE_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MY_TABLE_seq")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable")
    private MyTableView myTableView;
}
```

And an Immutable entity (the reason for this is that it is a database view):

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Immutable
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE_VIEW")
public class MyTableView {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, length = 18)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private MyTable myTable;
}
```

Updating and creating the MyTable works without a problem. The problem start when I try to remove the MyTable. I am using the repository for that:

```
public interface MyTableRepository extends CrudRepository<MyTable,Long> {
}
```

In the service I am using:

```
public void deleteMyTable(Long id){
/*fetch the my table enity*/
   myTableRepository.delete(myTable);
}
```

Nothing happens. No exception nothing at all. What I have tried is changing the @OneToOne mapping. With different cascade:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable",cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable",cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable",cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTable",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

- ALL,MERGE and REMOVE throws and exception as I can not delete from a
  view
- DETACH,REFRESH and PERSIST does nothing but the MyTable entity is not
  removed

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you remove @Repository annotation also transactional can be put to service layer? Spring data automatically scan the packages for you.

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Yes I can do that

Comment: As I understand from your code you try to delete from table and view automatically will be updated

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez : Yes that is correct

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez : In the end I want to be able to remove the table and by doing that refreshing the view as well. Because I cannot delete from the view

Comment: You can't delete view you can only delete from table and view will be refreshed automatically

Comment: According to behavior of view, it will be created when sql is queried

Comment: You are talking about database view right?

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez Yes I am talking about a database view

Comment: @Arion I am not sure if it will work, but have you tried to set to `null` the relationship with `MyTable` in `MyTableView` before deleting `MyTable`? Please, try including something like `@PreRemove
private void unsetMyTableInView() {
  myTableView.setMyTable( null );
}` in `MyTable` and test your code again. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763863/delete-hibernate-entity-without-attempting-to-delete-association-table-view) perhaps can be of help as well.

Comment: @jccampanero it will still try to do a delete on the view when setting the view to null

Comment: Hi @Arion. Thank you very much for the feedback. I am sorry to hear that it doesn't work. In fact, sorry, because it makes sense according to how the relationship between the entities is established. Please, can you try again but inverting the relationship ownership? I mean, in `MyTable` define the following: `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id") private MyTableView myTableView;`. In `MyTableView` simplify your relationship as this: `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTableView") private MyTable myTable;`. If you think about it, as `MyTableView` is a view, defining the relation

Comment: like that makes more sense.

Comment: @jccampanero that worked. simplifying the mapping and making it the other way around worked. If you put that in a nice answer I can give you the bounty. I agree it make sense

Comment: That is great @Arion!! I am very happy to hear that it worked. I let an answer with this information. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the question comments, I suggested you to try creating some kind of `@PreRemove` hook in order to avoid the problem.

Because it makes perfect sense according to how the relationship between your entities is defined.

But if you think about that, you are dealing with a view, with a read-only entity: in my opinion, it makes more sense to invert the relationship and make `MyTable` the owner. In addition probably it will solve the issue.

Please, consider define you relationship with `MyTableView` in `MyTable` like this:

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private MyTableView myTableView;
```

In `MyTableView`, simplify your relationship with `MyTable` in the following way:

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "myTableView")
private MyTable myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the constraint on the mapping.
An alternative way to remove "MyTableView" instance when deleting "MyTable" is to set "orphanRemoval = true". I think this is better for a double OneToOne mapping.
there are some links that (i hope) may helps you :

[Hibernate one to one mapping. Delete row from dependent table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44125432/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-delete-row-from-dependent-table)

[How does JPA orphanRemoval=true differ from the ON DELETE CASCADE DML clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329577/how-does-jpa-orphanremoval-true-differ-from-the-on-delete-cascade-dml-clause)

Comment: I tried with the orphan removal. It still tries to do a delete on the view which doesn’t work